# How can i upgrade to python 3.11 on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, fast-ai, ubuntu-22.04

I have recently shifted from windows 10 to linux (ubuntu 22.04). I have recently installed anaconda  + fastai using terminal to learn ML. I want to upgrade my python (3.9) to python 3.11.

What are the steps to follow (considering , i am a beginner in linux ) ?
Also It should not cause bad issues to my fastai library.
Thankyou.

I tried this method :
[python-3-11-released-how-install-ubuntu /](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/10/python-3-11-released-how-install-ubuntu/)

At last , my terminal shows this , after i selected python3.11 auto mode.
[image: my terminal screenshot]

But after this, when i run jupyter notebook and checked the python version , it shows python 3.9
[image: version check in jupyter]

What should i do ? please Help.

Answer (score -1):

If juypter notebook was installed using conda, then you can run:

```
conda install ipython jupyter
```

and restart juypter notebook for it to take effect.

Comment: Python version didn't upgrade .
Only ipython , conda, jupyter, openssl upgraded with that code.

Comment: You probably also need `conda install -c conda-forge python`, see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python). However, make sure you use your Anaconda to **install this in a certain environment**. You won't want it becoming the version for everything **yet**. That [version came out **only three days ago**](https://realpython.com/python311-new-features/) and likely will cause you massive headaches unless you've seen others using it with your entire tech stack. Is everything else you need on the conda-forge channel so you can use those versions and have everything working well?

Comment: <continued> See [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/navigator/tutorials/manage-environments/) about managing your environments with the Anaconda navigator, and [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#installing-a-different-version-of-python) for installing a different version of Python. It may not let you put `python=3.11` as a choice there since it is so new. So you'd need to install 3.10 first as you set up the environment and then when that environment is activate ' install the second Python version into it'.

Comment: Then make sure you are using that new environment to run Jupyter, too.

Comment: Note [this person, Sid Radcliffe](https://twitter.com/sidradcliffe/status/1584800655663042560) used `conda create -n py311 python==3.11`; but that was with mini-forge that has conda-forge as the default. That's not the company distribution that has the main channel as default. I'm assuming OP has main company distribution.